# NPM run script using cocurrently but conditioned by succesfull build

Tags: node.js, npm

prestart Scenario.

Node.js application
This is the "scripts" section in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {    
    "build": "tsc -p app/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p app/ --watch",
    "start_server": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start_dev": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run start_server\""
  }
```

To start the development server I run: `npm run start_dev`.

Thew problem is the fact that in this way if the build fails (= `tsc -p app/` return some error) I can't see it because the server is started anyway and the "watch" fill the console with continuous output.

I found many errors when I deployed the code in production and the "buil" script failed returning me the errors predsent in the code.

I want something like:

```
"start_dev": "\"npm run prestart\" THEN concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run start_server\""
```

so the `npm run start_server` is called only if the build command exit with "0" (no error).

Suggestion to achieve this result?
How can I run the "start_dev" "conditionally" to the "prestart" script?

Thanks,

Alex

---

[Update]
As a workaround I'm using a Windows batch file with this commands:

```
call npm run build

IF %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 GOTO :ERROR

:: no error, run it
npm run start_dev

GOTO END

:ERROR

echo.
echo.
echo Error level for build is "%ERRORLEVEL%".
echo Check the error(s).
echo.

pause

:END
```

Note. The use of "call" is necessary to prevent the shell to close in case of error on build.

Comment: Hi Alex, could you please provide a link to some info on `concurrently`? Based on your question, it looks like it's a CLI command you've downloaded but I've never heard of it.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently
I used it as found in some Angular2 tutorial (probably the official one).